# Use Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem to prove the convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_{n} n^{-a}$

Tags: probability-theory

I am working on a question that requires using Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem to prove the almost surely convergence of series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_{n} n^{-a}$. We are given: a $\geq$ 0, and $X_{n}$ iid Rademacher variables.

I am trying to find a good value A to define the truncated variable $Y_{n}$ in the definition of the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem). I am currently thinking of letting A = $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}]$ = 0 so that condition i is met. but this doesn't seem to help me with condition ii and iii. Could someone give me a hint on how to start the question? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is  not true that the series is almost surely convergent for all $a \geq 0$. (For  $a=0$ the general term of the series does not tend to $0$). In fact the series is also not almost surely convergent for $a \leq \frac 1 2$. For $a >\frac 1 2$ you can truncate at any point $A$. Take $A=1$ and note that $|X_n|n^{-a}=n^{-a}\leq 1$. Hence you only have to verify convergence of $\sum EX_nn^{-a}$ and $\sum var(X_nn^{-a})$ which is true for $a >\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful.